# How to create huggingface tokenizer from a "char_to_idx" dict?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

Given a dictionary `char_to_idx` how can one create a tokenizer such that the ids of the tokens are **guaranteed** to be the same as in char_to_idx?

```py
char_to_idx = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
tokenizer  = tokenizers.Tokenizer(tokenizers.models.Unigram())
# ???
print(tokenizer.get_vocab())
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple way to do it:

```
char_to_idx = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}

# This will do exactly opposite to char_to_idx as idx_to_char 
itos = {i:ch for i,ch in enumerate(char_to_idx)}
```

After this:

#This will make sure that you will get exact values for characters

```
decode = lambda l: ''.join(itos[i] for i in l)
```

Comment: Yes but that's not what I was asking for, thank you for an alternative solution.